# Why this img element is not being altered by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the src attribute of an img tag, deppeding on the result of an ajax request. This request returns a json and is everything ok with it, my if test is reaching the right portion of code, it shows the expected output at browser console but the src attribute is not being altered.

I already tried to remove this img element with:

```
$('#l'+generatedId).remove();
```

and than create a new one inside the parent element by doing:

```
$('#msgid'+generatedId).append('<img id="l'+generatedId+'" src="newpath" />');
```

but I had no success, nothing happens.

the "full" code:

```
var generatedId=0;

function doSomething(){

$('#msg').append('<p class="msg2" id="msgid'+generatedId+'" data-sid="msgid'+generatedId+'">'+$('#msgtxt').val()+'<img id="l'+generatedId+'" src="url/load.svg" /></p>');

$.ajax({
    data: $('#enviaChat').serialize(),
    url: 'assets/lib/msg.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    success:function(data){
        var msgReturn = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        if(msgReturn.status=='ok'){
        $('#l'+generatedId).attr('src','url/ok.png');
            }
          }
});
generatedId++;
}
```

I also wanted to change the "data-sid" attribute of the respective img tag
with the ID msgid value returned by the json but currently it also doesn't changes, what I think it's the same problem.

As I said, the console output in browser console window is as expected:

```
{"status":"ok","msgid":"8"}
```

**-- Edit1:**

guys, I added some code into the if "ok" condition

```
console.log('Before:'+$('#l'+generatedId).attr('src'));
$('#l'+msgnova).attr('src','url/msgok.png');
console.log('After:'+$('#l'+generatedId).attr('src'));


The result is First: undefined / After: undefined. So I guess the element is not being found. So the conlusio is the element is not in the DOM. Does anyone had this problem? I also tried to create the <p> parent first and then append the <img> but it doesn't work also.
```

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log( $('#l'+generatedId).attr('src'))`

Comment: Your code should work, if the json data is really the expected one. Did you try placing the `console.log()` (or a debugger breakpoint) *inside* that `if` statement, to check whether the condition evaluates as expected?

Comment: Are you sure that `$('#l'+generatedId)` exists in the DOM?

Comment: Yes, as you see, the first value of generatedId is 0 and than increases by 1. When I run console.log($('#l0').attr('src')) it returns the full url of the image.

Comment: @Bergi did you see my edit? Doing console.log($('#l'+generatedId).attr('src')); inside the if "ok" block, it returns undefined. So I guess the element is not in the DOM. Have you any idea of what it's not in DOM?

Comment: @SandroBenevides No, I can't tell why. How do you create it, with the HTML or dynamically? When  do you call `doSomething()`? And you are saying that when you (later) run the code in the devtools console, it does find the element?

Comment: @SandroBenevides Are you sure that `generatedId` is the right one? Notice that the `success` callback is asynchronous, and you are doing the increment *before* that happens. You might want to try putting the `generatedId++` line inside the callback, after you updated the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was a scope problem, for some reason the success block was not being able to "see" the element using jquery selector. The solution was create a variable and attribute the element on it:

```
var generatedId=0;

function doSomething(){

$('#msg').append('<p class="msg2" id="msgid'+generatedId+'" data-sid="msgid'+generatedId+'">'+$('#msgtxt').val()+'<img id="l'+generatedId+'" src="url/load.svg" /></p>');
**var createdElem = $('#l'+generatedId);**
$.ajax({
    data: $('#enviaChat').serialize(),
    url: 'assets/lib/msg.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    success:function(data){
        var msgReturn = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        if(msgReturn.status=='ok'){

        //line below was altered
        createdElem.attr('src','url/ok.png');
        //instead of $('#l'+generatedId).attr('src','url/ok.png');

            }
          }
});
generatedId++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to create a child element inside the parent by

```
$('#parentElement'+generatedId).append('<img id="#img'+generatedId+'" src="newpath" />');
```

make sure the parent node actually exists or the `append()` method will not work. Maybe try creating `$('#parentElement'+generatedId)` this element first (by appending) and then append the child image. I would've commented this but don't have those privileges yet. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I tried to append the parent than the child but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the # in id attribute when appending the img Tag. You dont want the actual id attribute to have an '#' in it, it's only required as jquery selector:

`$('#msgid'+generatedId).append('<img id="l'+generatedId+'" src="newpath" />');`

Comment: sorry about that, it doesn't exists in the real code.

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` is asynchronous, and you have `generatedId++;` right after ajax request. You need to move it inside the success function after you have changed the src.

When your POST response comes back, your generatedId has already incremented and unable to find the generatedId in DOM.

```
$.ajax({
    data: $('#enviaChat').serialize(),
    url: 'assets/lib/msg.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    success:function(data){
        var msgReturn = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        if(msgReturn.status=='ok'){
            $('#l'+generatedId).attr('src','url/ok.png');
            generatedId++; // move here
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: No, it wasn't this. The generatedId is increased at the end of the function. I think the problem was scope, I answered to the question with the solution. Thank you anyway.

Comment: How did you know this was not the issue in your question? Did you even try this? The solution you have is a better way of addressing  it by creating a local variable to get a reference when your ajax request has resolved, but then it was not a scoping problem.

Comment: The first value of generatedId is 0 and the problem occurs right in the first execution, so the element has id l0 and even with the same id wasn't working. I commented out my solution and have tried yours but it didn't work. As I said, I don't know if is scope, I think it was LOL.